# Error 2002 when logging in at phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, configuration, phpmyadmin

I just downloaded and installed phpMyAdmin. When I try to login at http://mydomainname.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php I get the following message: 
" #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server". I think there is something wrong with my configuration. I have already googled on this error, but nothing I found worked. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Could you tell your OS? Is it `mac`?

Comment: Where and how do I need to try accessing MySQL? I'm not a pro when it comes to databases... Where do I need to fill in that line?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting "#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server" when logging in to phpmyadmin, try editing phpmyadmin/config.inc.php and change:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

to:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

[answer source blog](http://blog.ryantremaine.com/2011/03/2002-cannot-log-in-to-mysql-server.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried that, unfortunately didn't work... It then still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure MySQL is running.

Then try accessing the MySQL shell to see if you have the right username, password, and permissions set...

```
mysql -u root -p
```

If root has no password set, don't use the "-p" switch.

If you can get in, then `quit` and instead of root use whatever username/password to try again.

It's probably an issue with the account's set `Host:` field.

Comment: Where and how do I need to try accessing MySQL? I'm not a pro when it comes to databases... Where do I need to fill in that line?

Comment: @user3593846, Are you using Windows? Start > All programs > Accessories > Command Prompt. Or just type cmd.exe into Start's search box.

Comment: I can't access the MySQL via command prompt unfortunately. Got any other options? Really want to get this working ;).